# I want to trigger a mail whenever a new line item (row) added in Sharepoint and also want a escalation emails as per his Heirarchy chart

Tags: sharepoint, triggers, power-automate

I want to initiate a mail to a person who is lowest in the hierarchy chart. After Initial mail i want power automate to read sharepoint status whether team gave any feedback or not. If there is no response from the team in 48 hours, then again send a mail to his reporting supervisor. If still no response from supervisor then again initiate mail to supervisor's reporting manager.

I tried to create Workflow & and add trigger points in Power Automate but unable to do so

Comment: "*I tried to create Workflow & and add trigger points in Power Automate but unable to do so*" Please add more details to the question about your existing attempt and where it fell short.